# How to assign values to attributes of a complex type using class generated by MS XSD utility?

Tags: c#, xsd, xsd.exe

I've the following piece of code in my XSD file:

```
<xs:complexType name="CONSIDERATION" mixed="true">
        <xs:complexContent mixed="true">
            <xs:restriction base="xs:anyType">
                <xs:attribute name="_Description" type="xs:anySimpleType"/>
                <xs:attribute name="_Type" type="xs:anySimpleType" use="required"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
```

I'm using Microsoft XSD utility to generate the strongly typed class. Now when I want to assign "_Description" and "_Type", I don't find these attributes in the class. The generated class has the following code for the class:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.1432")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
    public partial class CONSIDERATION {

        private string[] textField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
        public string[] Text {
            get {
                return this.textField;
            }
            set {
                this.textField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

There's only Text property available to assign value to it. How can I assign value to the attributes description and type?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if XSD.exe even supports mixed="true" types (mixins ?). You should try to see what got generated from a type that has CONSIDERATION in it's type hierarchy definition. Maybe you'll find your fields there.
This is a case of type system impedance mismatch as the concept the schema is trying to define does not properly match .NET type system (single inheritance). Just try to wrap you head around `<xs:restriction base="xs:anyType">` and what it should mean from .NET point of view :).